# Why are these identical Jekyll sites building differently?

Tags: ruby, build, jekyll, github-pages, gemfile

Here are the links for the two sites and their code repositories:

[Theme site](http://scribble.muan.co/2013/05/06/more-post/)
[Theme GitHub repo](http://github.com/muan/scribble)

[My site](http://briennakh.github.io/2013/05/06/more-post/)
[My GitHub repo](http://github.com/briennakh/briennakh.github.io)

I downloaded the theme site's repo as a ZIP file, unzipped it, then pushed it to my GitHub repo to create my site. Why are the two sites building differently? If you look at the code blocks, you can see that the HTML is being rendered differently. Does this have something to do with the Gemfile?

Notes:

- This difference still exists without the `_site` folder that was added in the second repo.
- My site, when served locally, builds the same as the theme site on GitHub Pages

Answer (score 1):

Your template uses pygments for syntax highlighting https://github.com/briennakh/briennakh.github.io/blob/8d2d6479cb203e37cbc2223838b165c5cfba48cf/_config.yml#L18

However, Github Pages has switched to Rouge https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

FWIW, they should be very compatible, Rouge emits the same output.

Looks like someone documented how they did it over here: http://idratherbewriting.com/2016/02/21/bug-with-kramdown-and-rouge-with-github-pages/

Comment: The theme also uses pygments. I know to convert to rouge and kramdown. My question is just about why are the builds different when the code is supposedly identical?

Comment: Because pygments was available when the theme creator rendered their theme, and is not available for you, now, on GH Pages. Your environments are different. The code said to paint a picture, but your paintbrush is missing.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm surprised that their theme still works -- shouldn't it also break like mine, since it's being served by the same host? GitHub Pages retains older environments?

Comment: Oh, I assumed it builds the site when you push, and then just serves the built files. If that's true, then it's a question of when you built the site vs when the creator built the site. If not, then IDK.

Comment: Yeah, it says "Using Jekyll as a static site generator with GitHub Pages" https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/ The "static site" part is what means it does this.

Comment: lol, I'm kinda bored, so I was going to go make a PR to fix the thing, but checked existing PRs first, and saw https://github.com/muan/scribble/pull/39 ^_^